# Java - wrong input saved and printed into a 2D array of chars

Tags: java, arrays

THE PROBLEM : Wrong Output when I print the array. Chars read via the file have not been read properly.

DETAILS:

I cant save the character elements in the array properly and when I execute the program, when I print the array in which I saved the characters read from the txt file, the output is extremely wrong and incoherent. 
So in my program, the input is given via the command line, through a txt file. The txt file contains some char elements. Every row of the file's input, has no matter the file, the same elements. The chars from the input file have to be saved in a 2d array (I ignore the new line character when I save the elements from the txt file into my 2d array). The size of this array is known to me. Since concerning the input file, every line has the same number of elements so I can derive the number of rows.
This is the code I wrote but it gives wrong output. 
The input Give through the file:

```
+.........-
-+--------.
```

The wrong output :

```
++++++++++++++++++++........................................Number of lines: 2
Number of chars: 20
Number of columns: 10
```

So can you please help me by doing the necessary amendments in my code? I'm extremely new in Java and I can't tell why I get this wrong behavior of my code's execution.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class Doomday2 {
public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); 
    scanner.useDelimiter("");
    int numberOfLines = 0, count_chars=0, rows=0, i=0, j=0;
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        if(c == System.getProperty("line.separator").charAt(0)) {
            numberOfLines++;
            continue;
        }
        else count_chars++;     // do something with char
     }

    rows = count_chars /numberOfLines;
    //scanner.close();
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); 
    char[][] a = new char[1000][1000];
    while(scanner2.hasNext()){
        char c = scanner2.next().charAt(0);
        if(c == System.getProperty("line.separator").charAt(0)) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            for( i=0;i<numberOfLines;i++){
                for (j=0; j< rows; j++){
                 // System.out.print(a[i][j]);
                 a[i][j]=c; 
                 System.out.print(a[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
   // {
     //   System.out.print(a[i]);
   // }

   for( i=0;i<numberOfLines;i++){
      for (j=0; j< rows; j++){
          System.out.print(a[i][j]);

      }
   }
    System.out.println("Number of lines: " + numberOfLines);
    System.out.println("Number of chars: " + count_chars);
    System.out.println("Number of columns: " + rows);
    scanner.close();
    scanner2.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a clear problem statement.  Most people reading this won't have any idea about your previous question.

Comment: when I print the array the output is wrong. The array contains the chars of the txt file. The file consists only of char elements

Comment: Your `scanner2` doesn't have delimiter set to `""`. Also your line separation test if flawed. On Windows line separator is `\r\n` so `charAt(0)` will return only `\r` so when iteration over `\n` it will not match `\r` causing `count_chars++;` to execute. I don't know why you decide to handle each characters individually. Not to mention you never print any line separator which explains why entire output is in one line. Anyway why not read input as lines and then handle each of them as array of characters like answerers from your previous question suggested?

Comment: It is also not clear what you *really* want to achieve so it is strong candidate to be [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: If your goal is to read all characters from file (except line separators) into 2D char array then you can use `char[][] chars = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0])).map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);`. Then you can process that char array as you wish.

Comment: So, how can I read input from a file char by char and save it into a 2d array? Char By Char, cause i want to count the characters and new lines. Can u please provide some code? Im extremely confused and i cant get any help

Comment: It is not clear why *you* want to read it char-by-char. Why not let Java handle it like shown in my previous comment? If you need to know amount of characters then iterate over each row from `chars` array and get its length. You can do it via `int count = 0; for (char[] row : chars){ count += row.length}`, or if you know that each row has same amount of characters multiply amount of rows (`chars.length`) by amount of characters if first row (`chars[0].length` - assuming that file was not empty and there is first row).

Comment: I want to read it char by char and save them into a 2d array for the reason that, according to their position in the 2d array I will change their content. In C for example. If a[i][j]='+' I will implement a flood algorithm and change it into a[i][j]='-'. This is why Im stuck on this solution. I implemented it in C and it works perfectly and I want to implement the same idea in java

Comment: But what is stopping you from modifying that array when iterating over it instead of iterating over file?

Comment: I wouldn't judge it in terms "good/bad" but rather "easier/harder". Java is more focused on objects, so it tries to save programmer from lower level work like reading text char-by-char (so he wouldn't need to pay attention to different potential line separators, encodings and such), but provides ways to read it as chunks (most often lines) represented by String objects. Later if programmer want it is possible to process those strings as needed.

Comment: @pshemo char[][] chars = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0])).map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);
How could i write this in java 7?